# How to find what language a PDA accepts?

Tags: automata, pushdown-automata

Given the following PDA describe the language it accepts.

```
Q = { q0, q1, q2 }
Σ = { a, b }
Γ = { A, B }
F = { q1, q2 }
z = B
δ ( q0, a, B ) = { ( q0, AB ) }
δ ( q0, λ, B ) = { ( q1, λ ) }
δ ( q0, b, A ) = { ( q2, λ ) }
δ ( q0, a, A ) = { ( q0, AA ) }
δ ( q2, b, A ) = { ( q2, λ ) }
δ ( q2, λ, A ) = { ( q2, λ ) }
δ ( q2, λ, B ) = { ( q1, λ ) }
```

Answer: { ai bj | 0 ≤ j ≤ i }

Can somebody show me the steps to reach the answer. What general strategy/ steps are used to answer these type of questions?

Comment: Have you tried tracing the action of the PDA on some short strings to see if you can spot a pattern? In general, determining the language accepted by a PDA isn't simple, since there's no nice algorithm to do that.

Answer (score 0):

In the book, [*An Introduction to Formal Languages and Automata*](http://www.jblearning.com/catalog/9781449615529/) by Peter Linz, there is an algorithm to get the grammar accepted by the given pushdown automata. Getting the language from grammar is a very tedious task, and I don't think there is any algorithm for that.